# adding SetValueComparer to modelBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

just wondering how I can get rid of this warning:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10620]
> The property 'FI' on entity type 'Routes' is a collection or enumeration type with a value converter but with no
> value comparer. Set a value comparer to ensure the
> collection/enumeration elements are compared correctly.

Code:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Routes>().Property(l => l.FI).HasConversion(
                    FI=> String.Join(",", FI),
                    dbVal => dbVal.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
                );
```

where FI is defined in the model as:

```
public List<string> FI { get; set; }
```

I understand I have to do a SetValueComparer call somehow but I am not sure how. The examples on line are a bit different and don't have the String.Join and dbVal lines.

Thank you

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @jasie unfortunately not. Get error: ": error CS1501: No overload for method 'HasConversion' takes 3 arguments"
How do I keep the follow lines:  FI=> String.Join(",", FI),
                    dbVal => dbVal.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()

Comment: I updated my answer. Please update your question by adding the definition of FI, or better the code of the l entity.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you put more effort into code indentation and member naming (l, FI??). It would make your code so much more readable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5#mutable-classes) - this is a example of how to set a value comparer (inside of `HasConversion()`):

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<EntityType>()
    .Property(e => e.MyListProperty)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
        new ValueComparer<List<int>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => c.ToList()
        )
    );
```

You need to choose the appropriate value comparison, of course (`List<string>` instead of `List<int>`, for example).

UPDATE: adapted to your code snippet, it should look like this (don't know, if it works, though):

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Routes>()
    .Property(l => l.FI)
    .HasConversion(
        fi => String.Join(",", fi),
        dbVal => dbVal.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList(),
        new ValueComparer<List<string>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => c.ToList()
        )
    );
```